# How to schedule an Airflow Job to run on alternate days

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow Job which is running daily at the moment but I need to run it on alternate days. I want to know if this code will work correctly or if there is a better way to do it?

```
dag = DAG(  
        dag_name,
        default_args=default_args,
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
        schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=48)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use cron format, if you want to schedule the DAG to run every two days i would use:

schedule_interval='0 0 */2 * *'

[image]

Check [this](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*/2_*_*)